# how to protect your php code or hide it

Tags: php

hi i take look inside some php files and find that the php inside is hidden or encrypted ,it's like  this

```
<?php 
echo "<div\x20\x69d\x3d\x22s\x69deba\x72\x22>\n\t";
if(is_active_sidebar("\x72igh\x74-\x73i\x64\x65\x62a\x72-s\x69n\x67\x6ce-\x70\x61g\x65"))
{
    echo "\t\t";
    dynamic_sidebar("\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74-s\x69de\x62\x61r-\x73i\x6e\x67\x6ce-pa\x67e");
    echo "\t";
}
echo "\n</\x64\x69v>\x20\x3c!--\x65n\x64\x20\x23s\x69\x64e\x62\x61\x72-->\n\n";
?>
```

or

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48NXJ0IDFsNXJ0LTVycjJyJz48NCBjbDFzcz0nNGMybi1yNW0ydjUnPjwvND4gQ1VSTCBQSFAgNXg1bnQ0Mm'));?>
```

so what's the difference between the both and how we can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not crypting but encoding, the later on is about a file identifier.

It can be done by encoding/decoding text in hexadecimal instead of ascii see http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm

or by using escaped unicode see https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ <= this is your case

Comment: thnx , yes i find  difference between the both but how i can do this